# ¿Cómo detectar si un valor es un float con coma, independientemente de la cantidad de decimales?

Tags: php, php7

Actualmente, he llegado a desarrollar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
(preg_match ('/^(-){0,1}([0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9][0-9])*([,][0-9]{1,'.$numDecimales.'}){0,1}$/', $numero) == true)
```

Sin embargo, la desventaja que tiene es que, si el valor que se le pasa al método tiene una cantidad de decimales superior al valor de $numDecimales, el método interpreta que dicho valor NO es un decimal.

¿Cómo puedo eliminar dicha limitación?

Comment: Y no es mas facil redondearlo y luego preguntar si son lo mismo?

Comment: ¿La función [is_float()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-float.php) no te sirve?

Comment: no me queda clara tu pregunta... por el hecho de que mencionas float con comas... los float regularmente no tienen comas, si no un punto decimal... entonces si estas trabajando con estandares numericos seria conveniente presentar un grupo de numeros, la evaluacion erronea que hace tu script y los que esperas como resultado.

Comment: @gbianchi no por que segun el enunciado no es un numero standar.

Comment: @Marcos estoy casi seguro que no funciona con decimales separados por coma ...

Answer (score 1):

Tienes problemas con tus cuantificadores.

Los cuantificadores afectan a los elementos que lo preceden:

- `{n}` : Se repite `n` veces
- `{n,m}` : Se repite entre `n` veces y `m` veces
- `{n,}` : Se repite un mínimo de `n`
- `{,m}` : Se repite un máximo `n` veces
- `?` : Se repite cero o una vez, lo mismo que `{0,1}`
- `*` : Se repite cero o más veces, lo mismo que `{0,}`
- `+` : Se repite una o más veces, lo mismo que `{1,}`

Entonces para saber si es un número comenzamos con el signo, el cual puede o no existir (cero o una vez `?`)  -> `[-+]?`

Luego una cantidad indeterminada de dígitos que pueden estar entre una o muchas veces (`+`)  -> `\d+`

Y que tenga una coma acompañado de 1 o muchos dígitos (`+`)-> `(,\d+)`, este elemento puede estar cero o una vez (`?`) (**OJO con esto**) --> `(,\d+)?`

Juntamos todo y agregamos los marcadores de posición `^` y `$`; y tenemos:

```
^[+-]?\d+(,\d+)?$
```

Lo anterior determina un formato para números, pero lo que tu quieres es determinar si tiene decimales, por lo que solo necesitas quitar el cuantificado `?` del final para especificar que lo quieres siempre una vez

```
^[+-]?\d+(,\d+)$
```